# bash to select file, run grep, and rename in a new already created directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to `select` a file in a directory, run a `grep` on it, and then rename it in a new directory that has already been created .  The `bash` below does all of the above except apply the rename to the file in the new directory. So, if `file1.txt` is selected, after the `bash` is run, that file is renamed to `file1_OTHER.txt` in the new directory.  It seems cl0se to working but not done yet.  Thank you :).

**Files directory**

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

**Bash**

```
# select file
printf "please select a file to analyze with entered gene or genes  \n"
select file in $(cd /home/files;ls); do 
  break
done
echo $file "will be used"

# enter gene input
printf "%s \n" "Please enter id, use a comma between multiple:"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
read -a id
for (( i = 0; i < ${#id[@]}; i++ ))
do
  printf "%s\n" "${id[$i]}" >> /home/list.bed
done

# match input with id
grep -wFf /home/list.bed /home/targets.bed > /home/match.bed
logfile=/home/process.log
for file in /home/$file; do
  echo "Start selected file creation: Date: $(date) - File: $file"
  bname=$(basename $file)
  pref=${bname%%.txt}
  cp -f "$file" /home/reads/"${pref%%_OTHER}.txt"
  echo "End selected file creation: $(date) - File: $file"
done >> "$logfile"
```

**new directory -- `/home/reads`** (desired output after the `bash` is executed`)

```
file1_OTHER.txt
```

Comment: _It seems cl0se to working but not done yet._ So what isn't working? what do you obtain?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out using the tool posted by @Cyrus.

Comment: @Chris Could you post the answer to the question below, then mark it accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below worked for me, I just needed to set the `IFS` so it wasn't looking for a `,` as the file separator.  Thank you :).

```
# enter gene input
printf "%s \n" "Please enter id, use a comma between multiple:"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$OLDIFS
read -a id
for (( i = 0; i < ${#id[@]}; i++ ))
do
printf "%s\n" "${id[$i]}" >> /home/list.bed
done

# select file
printf "please select a file to analyze with entered gene or genes  \n"
select file in $(cd /home/files;ls); do 
break
done
echo $file "will be used"

# match input with id
grep -wFf /home/list.bed /home/targets.bed > /home/match.bed
logfile=/home/process.log
for file in /home/$file; do
echo "Start selected file creation: Date: $(date) - File: $file"
bname=$(basename $file)
pref=${bname%%.txt}
cp -f "$file" /home/reads/"${pref%%_OTHER}.txt"
echo "End selected file creation: $(date) - File: $file"
done >> "$logfile"
```